# JQuery Datatable set height on column after fnUpdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a JQuery datatable, that I initializeby setting bAutoWidth to false. However after creating the table I need to loop over to edit one of the columns for each row to add a radio button. I do this through a for loop:

```
var rows = searchTable.fnGetNodes();
for(var row in rows) {
  var rowText = oTable.fnGetData(rows[row],0);
  var htmldata = $.parseHTML(rowText);
  var myId = $(htmldata).attr("id");
  var replaceHtml = '<input type="radio" id="' + myId +'" />';
  oTable.fnUpdate(replaceHtml ,parseInt(row),0);
}

$("#my-table").css("width","100%");
```

fnUpdate destroys the widths I set in my datatable definition, which is why I reset the width after the loop, but the column width's are still incorrect. Is there a way I can reset the width per column after the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around, I didn't really find an answer/function to setting the width on the column after a fnUpdate.

In my case I got around this by setting the column width in a css file for the div:

```
.radio-div{
  input{width: 50px; display: inline-block;}
  p{margin-top: 5px;}
}
```